# onClick overrides Semantic UI's dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

Dropdown functions normally until I add onClick(). I guess Semantic UI has some built in functions for onClick() so when I call it, the item does not show up as selected choice with the option to "x" out.

onChange() does not work.

```
class Wines extends Component {

  state = {
    wines: [],
    list: []
  };

  handleDropdown = (event, {value}) => {
    this.setState({ list: value})
    console.log(value)
  }

  render() {
    const options = [
      { key: 'France', text: 'France', value: 'France', onClick: this.handleDropdown },
      { key: 'Spain', text: 'Spain', value: 'Spain'},
      { key: 'Portugal', text: 'Portugal', value: 'Portugal' }
    ]

    return (
      <Dropdown placeholder='Countries' fluid multiple selection options={options} />
    )
  }
}

export default Wines;
```

Comment: You are missing a comma after `value: 'France'`, is it just a typo in your stackoverflow post?

Comment: Just a typo, sorry, I removed some styling @Hawkings

Comment: When you click on an entry, you want that option to be disabled. Is that your intended behavior?

Comment: disabled? No. I want it to be a selection. So they can choose multiple countries.

Answer (score 0):

More likely than not, it is working as intended. I checked the docs of the Semantic UI dropdown [here](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#types-dropdown). It doesn't do anything in that regard for you in a magic-y way.

One issue is that you aren't building a list inside your click handler. You just keep replacing the value you just clicked on. You need to build on top each time

```
setState({ list: [...this.state.list, value] })
```

As mentioned before, it doesn't do any magic for you, so you have to modify the props yourself, based on the items that you have placed in `this.state.list`. I suggest mapping over the array again, so you don't have to repeatedly hard code the equality check for every entry.

```
const options = [
    { key: 'France', text: 'France', value: 'France', onClick: this.handleDropdown },
    { key: 'Spain', text: 'Spain', value: 'Spain'},
    { key: 'Portugal', text: 'Portugal', value: 'Portugal' }
]

const optionsToRender = options.map(dropdownEntry => {
    if (this.state.list.includes(dropdownEntry.value)) {
        dropdownEntry.somePropYouWantToChange = 'some value you want to assign it to'
    }
    return dropdownEntry
})

<Dropdown placeholder='Countries' fluid multiple selection options={optionsToRender} />
```